# Why does the link in the subpage not work?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I don't understand, why the link in the subpage doesn't work? when I click on the link 'some link' it doesn't send me on google page

```
<ul class="tabs">
   <li><a href="#tab1">1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#tab2">2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#tab3">2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#tab4">4</a></li>
</ul>`enter code here`
<div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
   <a href="https://www.google.com/">some link</a>
</div> 
<div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
   <a href="https://www.google.com/">some link</a>
</div> 
<div id="tab3" class="tab_content">
   <a href="https://www.google.com/">some link</a>
</div> 
<div id="tab4" class="tab_content">
   <a href="https://www.google.com/">some link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Works for me. Must be some html, css or code missing that causes the problem.

Comment: it is not full code. in full code it doesn''t work and I think maybe thi link is in tab container?

Comment: If you copy the code you provided and save it into a file (`test.html`), you can open it on any browser and it clicking the links should take you to google just fine. We need more code.

Comment: If that link is not clickable then some tags was over laped with this a tag. Please check this in inspect element in browser

Comment: Please send the jquery code you wrote for the above HTML tabs

Comment: Check if you have any e.preventDefault or return false in your js , for these  a tags.